# WCF: change maxStringContentLength

Tags: wcf

I need to change the maxStringContentLength to a value larger than 8192 but have not been successful in doing it. My WCF service will generate an exception if the amount of data it receives is greater than 8192 bytes. I have exhausted my searches and nothing seems to help. I should point out that the exception comes from the server. Forget about the client because I am seeing the exception generated straight from WCF on the server. Here is my web.config settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="defaultBinding">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="1048576" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```